# mongodb ubuntu amazon web service

Tags: php, mongodb, ubuntu

I have this query

> db.tablebusiness.find({ "LongitudeLatitude" : { "$within" : { "$centerSphere" : [[106.772835, -6.186753], 0.0089967464101566] } }, "indexContents" : { "$all" : ["warung"] }, "Prominent" : { "$gte" : 15 } }).limit(50);

the problem: in mongodb windows this query running quickly less than 1 second but in ubuntu server amazon this query not running. Took 1 minute.

Of course there are issues like lower memory in amazon server (my local host has 8GB memory). However the difference in performance is HUGE.

In my local server, for example, I can freakin run 1000000 thread. That amazon thingy runs only like 1 or 2 queries.

Both are indexed. Actually the amazon server is t he exact copy of the my localhost. I simply uploaded the file from localhost to amazon.

They are both indexed. In fact, recently I added additional index to the amazon.

The indexes for localhost are:

```
{LongitudeLatitude :"2d",indexContents :1,Prominent:-1}
```

The indexes for amazon are:

```
{LongitudeLatitude :"2d",indexContents :1,Prominent:-1}
```

We also add

```
{LongitudeLatitude :"2d",Prominent:-1} latter to no effect
```

Does anyone know what is wrong in my ubuntu server amazon?

dbserever at localhost is

```
db.runCommand("buildInfo")
{
        "version" : "2.0.7",
        "gitVersion" : "875033920e8869d
        "sysInfo" : "windows sys.getwin
 platform=2, service_pack='Service Pack
        "versionArray" : [
                2,
                0,
                7,
                0
        ],
        "bits" : 64,
        "debug" : false,
        "maxBsonObjectSize" : 16777216,
        "ok" : 1
```

dbserever at ubuntu amazon is

```
 db.runCommand("buildInfo");
{
        "version" : "2.0.7",
        "gitVersion" : "875033920e8869d284f32119413543fa475227bf",
        "sysInfo" : "Linux ip-10-2-29-40 2.6.21.7-2.ec2.v1.2.fc8xen #1 SMP Fri Nov 20 17:48:28 EST 2009 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_41",
        "versionArray" : [
                2,
                0,
                7,
                0
        ],
        "bits" : 64,
        "debug" : false,
        "maxBsonObjectSize" : 16777216,
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the answer here is RAM - if you want queries like this to run fast in Amazon, then the data set they are working on (also known as the working set), that is indexes + data, must fit into RAM.  Any time you have to hit disk on the Amazon instance (page fault), you are going to be using EBS, which means you are going to be using the network.  This is not going to be fast compared to a local disk, and it certainly will be orders of magnitude slower than accessing the data in RAM.

If the Amazon instance has enough RAM but is still slow, then the data set may not yet be in memory (it would be on your local machine because you have likely inserted it on that machine and run these queries many times).  Have you compared a first run with a second?

Also, depending on your instance, you may not have enough CPU resources.  The micros and small instances do not have a lot of horsepower, and your query so somewhat complex - I would take a look at the CPU utilization on Amazon to make sure your instance sizing is adequate.

Finally, I will say that lots of people have MongoDB running in Amazon successfully, but you have to be aware of the limitations and the recommendations to get the most out of the EC2 environment.  There is an excellent presentation here about running in Amazon:

http://www.10gen.com/presentations/MongoNYC-2012/MongoDB-on-Amazon%20EC2

And there is the Amazon/EC2 notes page:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Amazon+EC2

Comment: Check answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524175/why-using-all-in-mongodb-is-much-slower and please tell me if I am wrong.