# Why using $all in mongodb is much slower?

Tags: mongodb

I asked a similar question before [Why $in is much faster than $all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12364377/why-in-is-much-faster-than-all) and the answer is the idea that $in (that scan more row and return more result) should be faster due to sorting or whatever.

I don't think it's the issue, so I test $all with just one item.

$all with only one item is equivalent with normal search right?

Here is the log without $all (I used 4700 test cases with 30 thread):

The issue now is not that $all is slower than $in. $all is simply slower than ANYTHING. Including basic search.

```
Thu Sep 20 17:27:05 [conn11] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: /^emic/ } ntoreturn:20 reslen:20 404ms
Thu Sep 20 17:27:05 [conn21] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: /^jakarta/ } ntoreturn:20 nreturned:20 reslen:1193 67ms
Thu Sep 20 17:27:05 [conn15] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: /^sap/ } ntoreturn:20 nscanned:20 nreturned:20 reslen:1138 219ms
Thu Sep 20 17:27:05 [conn5] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: /^ione/ } ntoreturn:20 reslen:20 326ms
Thu Sep 20 17:27:05 [conn20] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: /^phi/ } ntoreturn:20 nscanned:20 nreturned:20 reslen:1210 340ms
Thu Sep 20 17:27:05 [conn13] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: /^dentist/ } ntoreturn:20 nscanned:20 nreturned:20 reslen:1074 252ms
Thu Sep 20 17:27:05 [conn23] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: /^othe/ } ntoreturn:20 nscanned:20 nreturned:20 reslen:1048 113ms
Thu Sep 20 17:27:05 [conn9] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: /^kota/ } ntoreturn:20 nscanned:20 nreturned:20 reslen:1147 296ms
Thu Sep 20 17:27:05 [conn7] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: /^budi/ } ntoreturn:20 nscanned:20 nreturned:20 reslen:1068 250ms
Thu Sep 20 17:27:05 [conn16] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: /^atc/ } ntoreturn:20 reslen:20 364ms
Thu Sep 20 17:27:06 [conn21] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: /^mir/ } ntoreturn:20 nscanned:20 nreturned:20 reslen:1055 275ms
Thu Sep 20 17:27:06 [conn11] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: /^mogo/ } ntoreturn:20 nscanned:6 nreturned:6 reslen:347 325ms
Thu Sep 20 17:27:06 [conn5] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: /^pondok/ } ntoreturn:20 nscanned:20 nreturned:20 reslen:993 184ms
Thu Sep 20 17:27:06 [conn15] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: /^aneka/ } ntoreturn:20 nscanned:20 nreturned:20 reslen:1114 257ms
Thu Sep 20 17:27:06 [conn20] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: /^tv/ } ntoreturn:20 nscanned:20 nreturned:20 reslen:1154 173ms
Thu Sep 20 17:27:06 [conn7] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: /^t/ } ntoreturn:20 nreturned:20 reslen:1085 3ms
Thu Sep 20 17:27:06 [conn9] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: /^system/ } ntoreturn:20 nscanned:20 nreturned:20 reslen:1271 177ms
Thu Sep 20 17:27:06 [conn13] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: /^crepes/ } ntoreturn:20 nscanned:20 nreturned:20 reslen:1134 302ms
Thu Sep 20 17:27:06 [conn23] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: /^factor/ } ntoreturn:20 nscanned:20 nreturned:20 reslen:1324 340ms
Thu Sep 20 17:27:06 [conn16] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: /^baso/ } ntoreturn:20 nscanned:20 nreturned:20 reslen:1214 239ms
Thu Sep 20 17:27:06 [conn15] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: /^forward/ } ntoreturn:20 nreturned:20 reslen:1351 52ms
Thu Sep 20 17:27:06 [conn21] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: /^permai/ } ntoreturn:20 nscanned:20 nreturned:20 reslen:1268 318ms
Thu Sep 20 17:27:06 [conn11] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: /^eam/ } ntoreturn:20 reslen:20 311ms
Thu Sep 20 17:27:06 [conn5] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: /^elf/ } ntoreturn:20 nscanned:1 nreturned:1 reslen:80 319ms
Thu Sep 20 17:27:06 [conn20] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: /^anugrah/ } ntoreturn:20 nscanned:20 nreturned:20 reslen:1191 279ms
Thu Sep 20 17:27:07 [conn9] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: /^mac/ } ntoreturn:20 nscanned:20 nreturned:20 reslen:1234 282ms
Thu Sep 20 17:27:07 [conn13] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: /^happy/ } ntoreturn:20 nscanned:20 nreturned:20 reslen:1153 298ms
Thu Sep 20 17:27:07 [conn7] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: /^warding/ } ntoreturn:20 reslen:20 408ms
Thu Sep 20 17:27:07 [conn21] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: /^g/ } ntoreturn:20 nreturned:20 reslen:1220 3ms
Thu Sep 20 17:27:07 [conn23] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: /^otak/ } ntoreturn:20 nscanned:3 nreturned:3 reslen:204 336ms
Thu Sep 20 17:27:07 [conn16] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: /^nail/ } ntoreturn:20 nscanned:20 nreturned:20 reslen:1226 312ms
Thu Sep 20 17:27:07 [conn15] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: /^apotik/ } ntoreturn:20 nscanned:20 nreturned:20 reslen:977 195ms
Thu Sep 20 17:27:07 [conn11] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: /^kare/ } ntoreturn:20 nscanned:20 nreturned:20 reslen:1116 295ms
Thu Sep 20 17:27:07 [conn5] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: /^king/ } ntoreturn:20 nscanned:20 nreturned:20 reslen:1131 252ms
Thu Sep 20 17:27:07 [conn9] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: /^modern/ } ntoreturn:20 nscanned:20 nreturned:20 reslen:1069 252ms
Thu Sep 20 17:27:07 [conn20] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: /^dutamas/ } ntoreturn:20 nscanned:6 nreturned:6 reslen:396 326ms
Thu Sep 20 17:27:07 [conn21] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: /^course/ } ntoreturn:20 nscanned:20 nreturned:20 reslen:1185 237ms
Thu Sep 20 17:27:07 [conn7] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: /^elle/ } ntoreturn:20 nscanned:3 nreturned:3 reslen:180 349ms
Thu Sep 20 17:27:07 [conn13] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.000785114234121064
```

Here is the result if using $all

```
hu Sep 20 16:51:32 [conn11] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: { $all: [ /^ykai/ ] } } ntoreturn:20 reslen:20 1712ms
Thu Sep 20 16:51:33 [conn21] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: { $all: [ /^mnctv/ ] } } ntoreturn:20 reslen:20 1543ms
Thu Sep 20 16:51:33 [conn5] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: { $all: [ /^edric/ ] } } ntoreturn:20 reslen:20 1378ms
Thu Sep 20 16:51:33 [conn16] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: { $all: [ /^emobile/ ] } } ntoreturn:20 nscanned:1 nreturned:1 reslen:68 1435ms
Thu Sep 20 16:51:33 [conn15] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: { $all: [ /^foodfes/ ] } } ntoreturn:20 nscanned:1 nreturned:1 reslen:73 1657ms
Thu Sep 20 16:51:33 [conn20] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: { $all: [ /^consys/ ] } } ntoreturn:20 reslen:20 1698ms
Thu Sep 20 16:51:33 [conn7] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: { $all: [ /^nokiaw/ ] } } ntoreturn:20 reslen:20 1747ms
Thu Sep 20 16:51:33 [conn13] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: { $all: [ /^elf/ ] } } ntoreturn:20 nscanned:1 nreturned:1 reslen:80 1572ms
Thu Sep 20 16:51:33 [conn9] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: { $all: [ /^rmhku/ ] } } ntoreturn:20 reslen:20 1553ms
Thu Sep 20 16:51:34 [conn11] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: { $all: [ /^refly/ ] } } ntoreturn:20 reslen:20 1768ms
Thu Sep 20 16:51:34 [conn23] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: { $all: [ /^yuanita/ ] } } ntoreturn:20 reslen:20 1913ms
Thu Sep 20 16:51:34 [conn5] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: { $all: [ /^mediate/ ] } } ntoreturn:20 nscanned:2 nreturned:2 reslen:103 1543ms
Thu Sep 20 16:51:34 [conn15] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: { $all: [ /^diskus/ ] } } ntoreturn:20 nscanned:1 nreturned:1 reslen:70 1411ms
Thu Sep 20 16:51:34 [conn21] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: { $all: [ /^rico/ ] } } ntoreturn:20 nscanned:8 nreturned:8 reslen:486 1748ms
Thu Sep 20 16:51:34 [conn16] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: { $all: [ /^bismart/ ] } } ntoreturn:20 reslen:20 1643ms
Thu Sep 20 16:51:35 [conn13] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: { $all: [ /^livera/ ] } } ntoreturn:20 reslen:20 1502ms
Thu Sep 20 16:51:35 [conn20] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: { $all: [ /^kikirna/ ] } } ntoreturn:20 reslen:20 1693ms
Thu Sep 20 16:51:35 [conn11] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: { $all: [ /^factor/ ] } } ntoreturn:20 nscanned:20 nreturned:20 reslen:1324 1161ms
Thu Sep 20 16:51:35 [conn9] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: { $all: [ /^haytien/ ] } } ntoreturn:20 reslen:20 1679ms
Thu Sep 20 16:51:35 [conn7] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: { $all: [ /^harni/ ] } } ntoreturn:20 nscanned:1 nreturned:1 reslen:86 1994ms
Thu Sep 20 16:51:36 [conn23] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: { $all: [ /^otak/ ] } } ntoreturn:20 nscanned:3 nreturned:3 reslen:204 1912ms
Thu Sep 20 16:51:36 [conn5] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: { $all: [ /^bluenet/ ] } } ntoreturn:20 reslen:20 1598ms
Thu Sep 20 16:51:36 [conn21] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: { $all: [ /^topwan/ ] } } ntoreturn:20 reslen:20 1549ms
Thu Sep 20 16:51:36 [conn15] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: { $all: [ /^tobas/ ] } } ntoreturn:20 nscanned:1 nreturned:1 reslen:54 1596ms
Thu Sep 20 16:51:36 [conn16] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: { $all: [ /^imagen/ ] } } ntoreturn:20 nscanned:1 nreturned:1 reslen:55 1595ms
Thu Sep 20 16:51:36 [conn9] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: { $all: [ /^corocot/ ] } } ntoreturn:20 nscanned:2 nreturned:2 reslen:128 1280ms
Thu Sep 20 16:51:36 [conn13] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: { $all: [ /^pdor/ ] } } ntoreturn:20 reslen:20 1682ms
Thu Sep 20 16:51:36 [conn20] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: { $all: [ /^elcom/ ] } } ntoreturn:20 nscanned:1 nreturned:1 reslen:63 1865ms
Thu Sep 20 16:51:37 [conn11] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: { $all: [ /^delapan/ ] } } ntoreturn:20 nscanned:6 nreturned:6 reslen:358 1740ms
Thu Sep 20 16:51:37 [conn7] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: { $all: [ /^tato/ ] } } ntoreturn:20 nscanned:13 nreturned:13 reslen:863 1678ms
Thu Sep 20 16:51:37 [conn23] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: { $all: [ /^mac/ ] } } ntoreturn:20 nscanned:20 nreturned:20 reslen:1234 1197ms
Thu Sep 20 16:51:37 [conn5] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: { $all: [ /^dutamas/ ] } } ntoreturn:20 nscanned:6 nreturned:6 reslen:396 1455ms
Thu Sep 20 16:51:37 [conn16] query newisikotagte15.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.8317, -6.2426 ], $maxDistance: 0.0007851142341210646 }, indexWords: { $all: [ /^jeneiro/ ] } } ntoreturn:20 reslen:20 1466ms
```

Note: I am aware that using $all for just one word is kind of  useless, and that's the point.

I use one word to show that the problem is not on indexing, or the query it self.

In the future obviously I will use $all for 2 - 3 keywords. However, in this sample, I use just one words so that it's obvious that the problem is not in the fact that the result is different but something more fundamental.

$in is not problematic at all. There seems to be issues here: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1745 but I do not understand it. What is server-1745?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working as designed as answered in [Why $in is much faster than $all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12364377/why-in-is-much-faster-than-all) as answered.

> $all with only one item is equivalent with normal search right?

No, it is a different codepath and different operator.

MongoDB explains the difference [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-$all). $all matches all values as opposed to any (which $in does). There are further usage examepls [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operators/).

The relevant SERVER ticket that you want is [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1748). You can vote on this ticket.